# Camel Exceptions not being logged

Tags: spring, apache-camel, log4j

I'm using Camel 2.10.2 and I have the following configuration:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext" trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <errorHandler type="LoggingErrorHandler" level="INFO" logName="my.logger" id="webserviceLoggingHandler"/>

    <route id="webService" errorHandlerRef="webserviceLoggingHandler">
        <from uri="direct:webService" />
        <to uri="spring-ws:{{webservice.url}}?messageFactory=#messageFactory&amp;messageSender=#messageSender" />
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <to uri="log:my.logger?level=INFO"/>
        </onException>
    </route>
    <route id="validate">
        <from uri="activemq:validate" />
        <to uri="direct:webService" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I would expect this to log to the console. Instead what I'm finding is that exceptions (for example IOExceptions like certificate errors) are just being consumed and I really need them to be logged.

Debugging the code I can see that the SpringDefaultErrorHandler is being used and this is delegating to the LoggingExceptionHandler which has an injected CamelLogger which has a NOPLogger injected. This means that nothing is being logged at all.

After reading through the docs I am unsure if I need to implement a specific error handler and relevant onException handling, or if I should instead just use the log component, or a mix of the two as I have above?

Any guidance gratefully received.

many Thanks

Comment: I have now also tried adding the following errorHandler to my config

    <errorHandler type="LoggingErrorHandler" level="INFO" logName="com.myLogger" id="webserviceLoggingHandler"/>

and added a errorhandlerRef to myWebservice all to no avail, still nothing in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. My camel setup was fine. We recently upgraded from Camel 2.6.0 to 2.10.2. Reading the camel docs I found that from camel 2.7 slf4j was used for logging instead of commons-logging. I already had the log4j and slf4j jars but was missing the slf4j-log4j binding jar. This is what was causing all logging to go to an NOPLogger. Once I dropped the jar in it all works fine.

Thanks